# Vue js GET API call not working due to parameter issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js

I wrote an API call to get some details. it is written using Vue JS(the backend is ASP.NET).
But the request is not sent to the backend because I did a mistake while setting the parameter. But I can't identify what is wrong.

API CALL with parameter:

```
       var ul = `FilterViewID=NA&@FromDate=${reportFormatDate(
          this.report.fromDate
        )}&@ToDate=${reportFormatDate(this.report.toDate)}&@Location=${
          this.report.location
        }&@CatCode=${this.report.category}&@EventID=${
          this.report.event
        }&@DepartmentCode=${this.report.department}&@OrderType=1&@id=065631`;

        alert(ul);

        await this.$http
          .get(`/api/common/get-digest/` + "" + ul.toString())
          .then((response) => {
            this.passingString = response.data.PassingString;
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
            debugger;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            ShowError(this.$toast, error.message);
          });
```

backend function:

```
        [Route("get-digest/{parameterString}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetDigestString(string parameterString)
        {

              return Ok(parameterString);
        }
```

If I set the parameter like this `` .get(`/api/common/get-digest/` + "ul") `` ,It is hit the backend function. I can't understand what is wrong with data type `var` or `let`. For the `ul` I can't use `""` instead of `''`, because I used some bind values in the parameter. Please give me a solution for that. thank you.

Comment: First of all, all you need is `"/api/common/get-digest/" + ul`. This is basic string composition. I'd usually expect there to be a `?` between the route URL and the GET params, but your setup seems to not require that. Anyway, have you done any debugging so far? Like inspected the request in the browser's dev tools? Done any server-side debugging?

Comment: I'm not sure using `&` is totally valid in a path parameter. Or at least if it's valid in ASP.NET. Even if it is, you might need to be more explicit and mark it as `[FromRoute]`. With that said, I really don't see why you'd want that query as *one* string parameter. I'd expect it as a query string and the method to have a signature like `GetDigestString([FromQuery] string FilterViewID, [FromQuery] string FromDate, /* ... etc ... */)`